# upgrade database postgresql on jira confluence astlassian application 64bit .

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, jira, confluence, suse

I want to upgrade database postgresql from version 8.3 to 9.0 on Jira application.

Which RPM should be used to work with Suse SLES10.3 64bit?
How to install Postgresql 9.0 in parallel to Postgresql 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

The best bet to find packages for SUSE distributions is the [openSUSE Build Service](http://en.opensuse.org/Build_Service).  The direct links there are a bit of a pain, so please look for yourself.

Parallel installation of multiple major PostgreSQL versions is not yet possible using SUSE RPMs.  If you need to do that, you will probably need to build from source.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. could you give me some information what should i do if i want to upgrade postgresql on altassian?